# Okular file chooser dialog is tiny!

Tags: okular, dialog

Recently the file selecter dialog in Okular has become tiny and very difficult to use (see below). Other KDE applications such as KSnapshot and KTorrent are unaffected. How can I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem by renaming `~/.kde/share/config/okularrc` to `okularrc.OLD`.